# How to insert a space between two variables in JSP?

Tags: html, forms, jsp, el

I have one line of html in a form on a JSP page like this:

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${set}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="thing" value="${entry.key} ${entry.value}">
</c:forEach>
```

However, the space between the key and the value `${entry.key} ${entry.value}` is lost when the form is submitted. I've tried using a `\` before the , in that case both the `\` and the  are still there when submitting.

It seems that Java EL does not preserve isolated spaces, is that right? If so, is there a valid workaround?

EDIT: This is so silly of me, many thanks to Cthulhu. But I still don't understand the behavior after adding a `\`. Why would that cause the space to show?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can insert white-spaces using:   `&nbsp;`

**[Character Entity References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)**

**Edit**: Seems to be a bug in the way spaces are handled by the EL parser, so you should use either html entities like `&nbsp;` or the other ways outlined [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2134454/759019).

Comment: Keep talking nonsense recently:( Thanks!

Comment: Sidenote: why inserting a \ changes the behavior of the space? Thanks!

Comment: But the whitespace is not ignored once the \ is inserted, and that's part of the reason that I didn't try &nbsp;, since I assumed it was the JSP compiler that did some tricks in there.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Seems to be a bug in the way the EL parser does processing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2134454/759019

Comment: Ha, that solves it completely. Thanks for digging up that post!

Comment: Note that `&nbsp;` is the entity for a *non-breaking* space. That’s not the same as entering a regular space character (it’ll stop the word after it from wrapping onto the next line), and doesn’t work if you’re trying to output your values into an HTML attribute like `class`.

Answer (score 4):

```
${entry.key}${' '}${entry.value}
```

was my way to fix this. Seems a little less verbose than the

```
<c:out value="${bean.foo} ${bean.bar} ${bean.waa}" />
```

from the other thread.