# Adding multiple classes to an HTML object with JSP

Tags: java, css, jsp

I am trying to add two classes to a div using JSP and the white space is getting trimmed. I found a question similar on here that suggested adding a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` to prevent trimming but that won't work here as this is a class declaration, not page copy. ANy suggestions?

```
<div class="${properties['class_1']} ${properties['class_2]}">
```

outputs

```
<div class="class_1class_2">
```

I need

```
<div class="class_1 class_2">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it simply like this :

```
<div class="${properties['class_1']}${' '}${properties['class_2']}">
```

Comment: I do believe you are mistaken http://jsfiddle.net/ka_tee_jean/6D5LP/ mac + chrome

Comment: Hum probably too much usage of `styleClass` in JSF, I'll try to find another alternative!

Comment: this works locally but will need to wait to test it in my QA environment... I'll update then

Answer (score 0):

have not done jsp in ahwile but something like :

```
${properties['class_1'] + " " + properties['class_2']}
```

Comment: This won't work as I don't believe you can concatenate inside of an HTML element... I could be wrong though

Comment: ok, will file it away. was thinking the $ might be similiar to @(razor) for .net.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `&nbsp;` or `&emsp;`. The first one is non-breaking white space, and the second one is breaking whitespace. I don't think it'll matter in either case for your use case.

[How to insert a space between two variables in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367921/how-to-insert-a-space-between-two-variables-in-jsp)

You can also try.

`<div class=<c:out value="${properties['class_1']} ${properties['class_2']}" />>`

Not sure how the JSP will handle nested tags like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an attribute that has a value of white space

```
<div class="${properties['class_1']}${pageScope.whiteSpace}${properties['class_2]}">
```